# Rust: why can't I pattern match a mut String Option inside a loop?

Tags: string, rust

I have this code here, where I try to extract some text based on a delimiter:

```
    //not working
    let mut text: Option<String> = None;
    for d in DELIMITERS {
        let split_res = full_text.split_once(d);
        if let Some((_, t0)) = split_res {
            let t = t0.to_string();
            match text {
                None => text = Some(t),
                Some(t2) => if t.len() < t2.len() {
                    text = Some(t); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8e4e0e8d7b2271b8f8ebd126896236ea

But I get these errors from the compiler

> ^^ value moved here, in previous iteration of loop

> note: these 2 reinitializations might get skipped

What's going on here?

Why can't I pattern match on text? Is the problem that my `text` variable gets consumed? I can't really understand where and how?

Changing the code to use `as_ref()` on `text` fixes the error but I don't understand why this is necessary:

```
    //working
    let mut text: Option<String> = None;
    for d in DELIMITERS {
        let split_res = full_text.split_once(d);
        if let Some((_, t0)) = split_res {
            let t = t0.to_string();
            match text.as_ref() {
                None => text = Some(t),
                Some(t2) => if t.len() < t2.len() {
                    text = Some(t); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not use `as_ref`, you are moving the object hence consuming it, so it is not available in the next iteration.

You can also match a reference:

```rust
match &text {}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=653f5ca2cda2dac5a5153e825430d76d)

Or you can [`take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.take) the inner value, leaving a `None` behind, that way you do not drop it. And since you re-assignate it afterwards keeps the same functionality:

```rust
const DELIMITERS: [&'static str; 2] = [
    "example",
    "not-found",
];

fn main() {
    let full_text = String::from("This is an example test");
    let mut text: Option<String> = None;
    for d in DELIMITERS {
        let split_res = full_text.split_once(d);
        if let Some((_, t0)) = split_res {
            let t = t0.to_string();
            match text.take() {
                None => text = Some(t),
                Some(t2) => if t.len() < t2.len() {
                    text = Some(t); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if let Some(t) = text {
        println!("{}", t);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4d8faa0ba637c090d5a065cd077b6c60)

Comment: The other problem already goes away once you fix the reference issue. Is there really another problem?

Comment: @hkBst, oh, its true, didn't realize about that.

Comment: I understand I'm consuming it, but since I'm reassigning it as well shouldn't it be consumable again as if I were creating a new one?

Comment: @heapOverflow, it do not work like that once it is moved is marked for being dropped. The compiler invalidates it.